# Access class based view from a method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class based view in a model. And I want to access it from a view method.

```
class GetAjaxViewUser():


def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And this is in a model. And, I want to access it from a view method, something like this:

```
def AjaxView(request):

    return GetAjaxViewUser.as_view()
```

Comment: What does it mean to have a view "in a model"?

Comment: Which means I added a new class in the model for doing some functions. Normally, no one do this. But, in my case, I separate each models and these are just specific to them.

Comment: I don't understand that either. What is a "new class in the model"? A model is already a class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I just defined another class. We can create multiple classes, right ..? And, the plugin I found for datatables-view only have class based views

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you upvote my question ? I am new to Django and I have so many doubts, therefore I put too many questions and now I can't ask questions anymore.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you check my last comment ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access cbv from another method like

```
return GetAjaxViewUser.as_view()(request)
```

But I wonder what would you want to achieve by this?

Comment: Yes. It works. if the classname is not defined. It's dynamic. So, its considered as a string and show the error, 'str' object has no attribute 'as_view'.This is what I am using now :  classname = "GetAjaxViewUser"
                return classname.as_view()(request)

Comment: I am changing all that now. Thanks. Can you upvote my question ? I am new to Django and I have so many doubts, therefore I put too many questions and now I can't ask questions anymore

Comment: I am new to Django and I have so many doubts, therefore I put too many questions and now I can't ask questions anymore. Mr. DanielRoseman downvoted me and can you upvote me ..?